# Applying if else conditions after fetching data from an API in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, api, get, conditional-statements

I am fetching data from an API and displaying it. (This part is working). So to get a better overview of what I'm trying to do:

- The user presses a button to take a test.
- This will fetch alcohol and temperature from my API: which is like {"alcohol":291,"temperature":25}
- If the alcohol and temperature are above a certain threshold give a  tick or a cross along with the reading
- Store this data in my Firestore as success or failure to do the test

The code:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ActivityIndicator, FlatList,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { auth, database } from '../config/firebase';
import { collection, doc, setDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { Alert } from 'react-native-web';

const url = "url";

function AlcoTestButton(){
  const [isLoading,setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [alcohol, setAlcohol] = useState();
  const [temperature, setTemperature] = useState();

  const fetchData= async ()=>{
    setTimeout(function(){
    setLoading(true)
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setAlcohol(json.alcohol);
        setTemperature(json.temperature);
   
        //send to database
        const sensorID = doc(collection(database, 'sensors'));
        setDoc(sensorID,{
          uid: auth?.currentUser?.uid,
          alcohol,
          temperature,
        });
       

      })
      .catch((error) =>{alert(error)})
      .finally(()=>{setLoading(false)});
      
    },5000);  
    }

    const checkToxic = () => {
        if ({alcohol}>250){
            console.log("ALERT")
        }
    }




  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity 
            onPress={()=>fetchData() && checkToxic()}
            style={styles.button}>
                <Text style={{ color: "white"}}>Take Test</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        {isLoading && (<ActivityIndicator />)}
        {!isLoading && !!temperature && !!alcohol && 
           <View>
              <Text>Alcohol = {alcohol}</Text>
              <Text>Temperature = {temperature}</Text>
           </View>
        }
    </View>

  )


}
```

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: problem is not clear

Comment: @UshanFernando It's an app for a breathalyzer (an IoT device) .. The user is taking a test. The mobile app is a way of interacting with the device. I wrote an API that takes reading from the sensors. When the user presses the button "Take Test", it retrieves this data from the JSON file. I'm trying to make an condition of : If the value of the alcohol sensor and the temperature sensor is greater than a certain threshold, it should display this to the user. In other words, you failed or you passed the test

Comment: can't you just use turnery operators and conditionally render it inside component?
{alcohol > 250 ? <Text>Too High</Text : <Text>Good </Text>

Comment: @UshanFernando Like this? const checkToxic = () => {

      alcohol > 250 ? <Text>Too High</Text> : <Text>Good </Text>
  }

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this. Please import useEffect first.

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (alcohol>250){
            console.log("ALERT")
        }
    }, [alcohol]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use useMemo like this:

```
const checkToxic = useMemo(()=>{
    return alcohol > 250
},[alcohol])
```

Now `checkToxic` will be updated every time `alcohol` changes. You can use it to conditional render a component.